# SwiftUI Trying to use MPMusicPlayerController and playbackState

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music

I am fairly new to SwiftUI, and I am struggling to use the Apple Swift Documentation. I'm trying to get the current state of the now playing music, hopefully printing something like

> paused

or

> playing

And so here is the code that I've come up with.

```
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

struct MusicView: View {
        
    @State var playbackState: MPMusicPlaybackState? = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.playbackState

    @State var updater = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onAppear(){
                print(playbackState)
            }
            .onReceive(updater){_ in
                playbackState = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.playbackState
                print(playbackState)
            }
    }
}
```

I'm finding it very confusing to use, and I don't understand why its constantly printing:

> Optional(__C.MPMusicPlaybackState)

I understand why it's optional, but why can't I get it to print some kind of state? And any source code that I seem to find is from 9 years ago in Obj-C. At this point, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift doesn't know how to translate that C enum into printable text for you. You could use a `switch` statement to print the values.

You could also listen for `NotificationCenter` updates for the state changes rather than use the `Timer`.

```
extension MPMusicPlaybackState {
    func printState() {
        print(self)
        switch self {
        case .interrupted:
            print("interrupted")
        case .stopped:
            print("stopped")
        case .playing:
            print("playing")
        case .paused:
            print("paused")
        case .seekingForward:
            print("seekingForward")
        case .seekingBackward:
            print("seekingBackward")
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
}

struct MusicView: View {
        
    @State var playbackState: MPMusicPlaybackState? = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.playbackState
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .onAppear(){
                playbackState?.printState()
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange)){ _ in
                playbackState = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.playbackState
                playbackState?.printState()
            }
    }
}
```