# How to get notified when iOS music app changes state

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, mpmediaplayercontroller

I have tried every possible method to subscribe and I'm not getting any notifications

```
let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
let appMusicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer
let queuePlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationQueuePlayer

func subscribe() {


    MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { _ in }      

    musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
    appMusicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
    queuePlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange, object: musicPlayer, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
        debugPrint("hello")
    }
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange, object: appMusicPlayer, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
        debugPrint("hello")
    }
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange, object: queuePlayer, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in
        debugPrint("hello")
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(playbackStateChanged(_:)),
        name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange,
        object: musicPlayer
    )

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(playbackStateChanged(_:)),
        name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange,
        object: appMusicPlayer
    )

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(playbackStateChanged(_:)),
        name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange,
        object: queuePlayer
    )
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly likely you are running app on simulator but go through this checklist if you are not.

- Add "NSAppleMusicUsageDescription" to your .plist file with string value
  which describes why you need access to Media player framework.
- Use sample code

  ```
  import SwiftUI
  import MediaPlayer

  struct ContentView: View {
      var body: some View {
          VStack {
              Image(systemName: "globe")
                  .imageScale(.large)
                  .foregroundStyle(.tint)
              Text("SetupMusic").onTapGesture {
                  setup()
              }
          }
          .padding()
      }
  }

  private func setup() {
      debugPrint("Requesting access")
      MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { permission in
          debugPrint("Setting up music player")
          let musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer
          musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()
          debugPrint("Initial State: \(musicPlayer.playbackState)")
          NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange, object: musicPlayer, queue: .main) {  notification in
              debugPrint("State changed to \(musicPlayer.playbackState)")
          }
      }
  }

  #Preview {
      ContentView()
  }
  ```

1. Run app on real iOS device. Simulator does not support MPMediaPlayer
   framework.
2. Hit button to allow for permission.
3. Once granted you should get initial state. (Stopped/Paused)
4. Go to system music app and play something on radio.
5. Launch app again you should see state change to Playing
6. Swipe down for notifications and pause music and state will change to
   Paused
7. Event will only be fired if app is in foreground state.

Comment: Hi this is very close, but I found a weird issue. This code only works if  debugPrint("Initial State: \(musicPlayer.playbackState)") is called, without that one line, the notification is not called. Any ideas why?

Comment: Reason is that observer is called before the state is ready to observe. So call to initial state adds states before start listening. Another way would to be something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68619784/swiftui-trying-to-use-mpmusicplayercontroller-and-playbackstate I don't know if tried it already.

Comment: I mean is this documented anywhere? How on earth does one know when a state is ready to be observed? And how would know what needs to be done to get it ready (in this case a state retrieval)

Comment: Its not documented anywhere. Calling any function of MusicPlaybackProtocol before registering seems to do the trick which must trigger something. All other notifications of Music player seems to work without it. I have seen some open source music app use it the same way.

Comment: Ok well that's really annoying...but also to clarify on your comment, there seems to be 4 notifications type, MPMusicPlayerControllerQueueDidChange, MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChange, MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange, MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange and only the volume one work without pre-triggering. You had it different?

Comment: Same as you. i tried MusicPlaybackProtocol other functions before the register. It seems to create the same effect.